# Embedly Failing to Extract MSN Domain

Tags: embedly

I can reproduce this: if you send this link to the Embedly Extract API: https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/as-advertisers-flee-musk-s-x-democrats-splurge-on-political-ads/ar-AA1lk0gR

It returns a `provider_url` of `https://www.msn.com/`. This has happened with multiple valid MSN article URLs.

Any ideas?